# Why I get this error when adding `url_launcher: ^6.1.5` to flutter app?

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I've created a new flutter project and added `url_launcher: ^6.1.5` to yaml file as dependency, when I run the app I get the following error. I have only this dependency. Checked different VPNs, Can open and download the jar files in Chrome, but still with no clue and can't run the app.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':url_launcher_android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':url_launcher_android:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.jar
   > Could not find builder-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.4.2/builder-3.4.2.jar
   > Could not find tracker-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/26.4.2/tracker-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find shared-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.4.2/shared-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find crash-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.4.2/crash-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.4.2/lint-gradle-api-26.4.2.jar        
   > Could not find gradle-api-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.4.2/gradle-api-3.4.2.jar
   > Could not find databinding-compiler-common-3.4.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.4.2/databinding-compiler-comm
on-3.4.2.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/26.4.2/manifest-merger-26.4.2.jar       
   > Could not find sdk-common-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.4.2/sdk-common-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/3.4.2/builder-test-api-3.4.2.jar       
   > Could not find ddmlib-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.4.2/ddmlib-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find sdklib-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.4.2/sdklib-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find layoutlib-api-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.4.2/layoutlib-api-26.4.2.jar       
   > Could not find dvlib-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.4.2/dvlib-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find repository-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools:repository:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.4.2/repository-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find common-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.4.2/common-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find bundletool-0.7.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.7.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.7.2/bundletool-0.7.2.jar
   > Could not find protos-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.4.2/protos-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find builder-model-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.4.2/builder-model-3.4.2.jar
   > Could not find apkzlib-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.4.2/apkzlib-3.4.2.jar
   > Could not find apksig-3.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.4.2/apksig-3.4.2.jar
   > Could not find annotations-26.4.2.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.4.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.4.2/annotations-26.4.2.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common-3.4.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.4.2).

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              3.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Flutter Doctor:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale en-US)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
version 33.0.0)
```

** build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find where the exact problem was. I went through bellow steps and could build the app on Android.

1. Deleted All Installed JDKs and JREs.
2. Deleted All environmental variables related to Android studio, JDK, and Flutter
3. Deleted `.gradle` and `.android` folder in `C:\Users\<you>\`
4. Deleted Android studio folder

---

5. Installed new Android studio stable version
6. Opened the existing flutter app deleted all the platform related folders, I mean `android`, `ios`, `linux`, `macos`, `web`, and `windows` inside the app. ran this command `flutter create .`, then ran the app on android phone. It went through all the necessary downloads and finally the app ran successfully.
   Note that I didn't installed any JDK, the Android studio picked the bundled JDK itself.

Answer (score 1):

Add *androidx* settings on your app...
go to `android/app/build.gradle` and add these on `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

then go to `android\gradle.properties` and add these

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

At the end execute `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` and run the app.

Answer (score 0):

In pubspec.yaml add version of url launcher as any and try again. It should fetch an appropriate version of the package

```dart
url_launcher: any
```

Comment: Not worked.....

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps you
[build fail when adding url_launcher to my project](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50001)

Comment: This also didn't work.

Comment: did you try 
flutter clean && flutter get

Comment: I did everything, still looking really frustrated.